# Proof of a complete set

Tags: logic

I have to prove this lemma:

Prove that if for no formula $z\not\in{S}$ the set $S\cup{\left\{{z}\right\}}$ is finitely satisfiable, then S is complete.

I don't understand a few things, for example; what is for no formula? I have an $r$ and I have to prove that $r$ or $ \neg$ $ r$ belongs to S. I have an idea using a valuate which is true so belongs to S.

thanks!

Comment: The hypothesis is worded a bit clumsily; it says that if $z$ is any formula not in $S$, then $S\cup\{z\}$ is not finitely satisfiable.

Answer (score 1):

"For no formula [stuff]" means "There is no formula such that [stuff]", or - equivalently - "For every formula, [not stuff]". The question is asking you to prove that IF there is no formula $z\not\in S$ such that $S\cup\{z\}$ finitely satisfiable, THEN $S$ is complete.

To do this, suppose $r$ is a formula; you need to prove that either $r$ or $\neg r$ is *provable from* $S$ (note that this isn't quite what you've written). So suppose $r\not\in S$; what does that tell you about $S\cup\{r\}$? What does that tell you about $S$ and $\neg r$?

---

If "complete" in your context means "*contains* $r$ or $\neg r$ for every formula $r$," then the lemma is false as stated: you need to assume either that $S$ is *deductively closed* or that $S$ is *finitely satisfiable* (a non-finitely satisfiable $S$ not containing every formula would be a counterexample, otherwise).

Comment: For a lemma, that this two sets are finitely satisfiable; S∪{r} and S∪¬r, but what can I do with that, I have to prove that either r or ¬r is provable from S.

Comment: @energy I don't think you understand my hint. Suppose $r$ is a formula; you need to prove that either $r$ or $\neg r$ is provable from $S$. If $r\in S$, you're done (why?), so suppose $r\not\in S$. Then what do you know about $S\cup\{r\}$?

Comment: Okey, so let me try, if $r \in S$ I can provable from S, I suppose than its not in S, I dont know anything about the union.

Comment: @energy Yes you do. You have a hypothesis of the form: "For every formula $z\not\in S$, ..." If $r\not\in S$, what can you conclude about $S\cup\{r\}$?

Comment: So this union set is finite satisfiable so exist a $S_0$ for each finite set in S in which all the formulas are true, so the set of r is true

Comment: @energy No, that's the opposite of what you can conclude. The assumption is "For every formula $z\not\in S$, the set $S\cup\{z\}$ is **not** finitely satisfiable". So you can conclude that $S\cup\{r\}$ is **not** finitely satisfiable. What does this mean about $\neg r$?